# Images are not loaded in some phone saying SecurityException PermissionDenial in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, permission-denied, android-contentresolver, android-securityexception

In android i am trying to take an image from gallery storing its URI and then pulling it back but its show SecurityException. Please help me. Thanks

```
ImageView: Unable to open content: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F70/NO_TRANSFORM/908138224
                                                                           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{12795c7f 18283:dccenter.dccenter.com.dccenter/u0a162} (pid=18283, uid=10162) that is not exported from uid 10106
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3833)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6084)
                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:3178)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1495)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1115)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:970)
                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:695)
                                                                               at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:784)
                                                                               at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:440)
                                                                               at adapter.SlidingImageAdapter.instantiateItem(SlidingImageAdapter.java:118)
```

My android Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

Comment: have you declare any permission in manifest?

Comment: yes i have given all the necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you declared the permission ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
```

if not, here is a simple solution:

```
public static final String KITKAT_VALUE = 1002;

  Intent intent;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
                            intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                        } else {
                            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(intent, KITKAT_VALUE);
                    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == KITKAT_VALUE ) {
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       // do something here
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir i declared that permission but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

this issue in marshmallow you can solve this by set the target to 22 or less
or support the runtime permission.
have a look to this blog post : [link] http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: I already set my target to 22 but its still not working in my galaxy view but in my moto g3 its show fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The image showed in Imageview after picking the image from gallery using

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, videoIdentifier);
```

and decoding the bitmap image from the URI

But saving the URI for future use and reopening the app and reusing the saved URI not worked. Couldn't decoding the bitmap from URI.

I solved the issue by extracting the original content uri from URI path

```
public String RemoveUnwantedString(String pathUri){
    //pathUri = "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/5213/ORIGINAL/NONE/2106970034"
    String[] d1 = pathUri.split("content://");
    for (String item1:d1) {
        if (item1.contains("media/")) {
            String[] d2 = item1.split("/ORIGINAL/");
            for (String item2:d2) {
                if (item2.contains("media/")) {
                    pathUri = "content://" + item2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //pathUri = "content://media/external/video/media/5213"
    return pathUri;
}
```